# What is EU VAT and Payment method additional fee is taxable in nopcommerce?

Tags: nopcommerce

Can any one know that when I enable the option of Payment method additional fee is taxable and **EU VAT**, at that time what should happening in the client side in nopcommerce eCommerce site?

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question and description both are different!!

**EU VAT** known as European Union value added tax.*A value-added tax (**VAT**), known in some countries as a goods and services tax (**GST**)* 
The configuration documentation you can find from here: [EU VAT configuration guide](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/EU+VAT+configuration+guide)

And for second one its self explanatory, additional fee of any payment method is taxable.

Comment: But, I want to tell that by enable this type of option then at client side where it is showing.